# Fill empty dates in array in PHP not working

Tags: php, mysql

on my website I would like to determine the daily active users per day of the current week. For this purpose, I have created an SQL query that shows me the number of users per day. Then I create an array from this, which I can use for my chart.
Since there is not a user online every day, I have to insert the empty date into the array. To do this, I did some research and then wrote the following code.

```
    $weekStartDate = '2022-03-21';
    $weekEndDate = '2022-03-27';

    for($cur_week_date = $weekStartDate; $cur_week_date <= $weekEndDate; $cur_week_date++) {
        $get_current_week_stats = $connection->prepare(" SELECT d.day, COUNT(DISTINCT IF(u.day = d.day, u.user_id, NULL)) AS current_week
                                                        FROM
                                                        (SELECT DATE(k.last_activity) AS `day`
                                                        FROM login_details k 
                                                        WHERE DATE(k.last_activity) = ?
                                                        GROUP BY `day`
                                                        ) AS d
                                                        JOIN
                                                        (SELECT DATE(l.last_activity) AS `day`, l.user_id
                                                        FROM login_details l 
                                                        WHERE DATE(l.last_activity) = ?
                                                        GROUP BY day, l.user_id
                                                        ) AS u
                                                        ON u.day <= d.day
                                                        GROUP BY d.day
                                                        ORDER BY d.day ");
        $get_current_week_stats->bind_param("ss", $cur_week_date, $cur_week_date);
        $get_current_week_stats->execute();
        $current_week = $get_current_week_stats->get_result();

        foreach($current_week as $row) {            
            // database result array
            $current_week_stats[] = $row;

            //customised array code
            $keys = array_keys($current_week_stats);
            $start = new DateTime('2022-03-21');
            $stop = new DateTime('2022-03-27');
            $stop->modify('+1 day');

            $range = new DatePeriod($start, new DateInterval('P1D'), $stop);
            $result = array();

            foreach($range as $key => $value) {
                $date = $value->format('Y-m-d');

                if(isset($current_week_stats[$date])) $result[$date] = $current_week_stats[$date];
                else $result[$date] = 0;
            }
        }   
    }

    $get_current_week_stats->close();

    echo json_encode(['current' => $result]);
```

**Database result array**

```
{"current":[
    {"day":"2022-03-21","current_week":2},
    {"day":"2022-03-22","current_week":1},
    {"day":"2022-03-23","current_week":2},
    {"day":"2022-03-24","current_week":1},
    {"day":"2022-03-25","current_week":1},
    {"day":"2022-03-27","current_week":1}
   ]
}
```

**Customised Array**

```
{"current":
    {
       "2022-03-21":0,
       "2022-03-22":0,
       "2022-03-23":0,
       "2022-03-24":0,
       "2022-03-25":0,
       "2022-03-26":0,
       "2022-03-27":0
    }
}
```

The problem is that the date of each day is displayed, but the active users are always zero.

What is the error here?

Comment: Please show the query `" ****Query**** "`

Comment: @Kendle added it

Comment: Thank you. Is `login_details` a table that you have added ?, a view? I can't find any reference to it in the documentation. Please give details.

Comment: @Kendle yes login_details is the table and last_activity is the timestamp when a user logged in.

Comment: Please try with this query `SELECT 
  DATE(last_activity) AS `day`,
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)
FROM login_details 
GROUP BY 
  DATE(last_activity)
HAVING
  DATE(last_activity) >= ?
  AND   DATE(last_activity) <= ? ;`